# Orchestrating Nested AJAX Calls Within Each Loop Before Chart Is Drawn (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, morris.js

I've been looking for an answer for this a couple of days now without luck.

I'm trying to build a chart from data collected via ajax calls to JSON REST Api. I use morris.js for building my charts. The data for chart is collected via 3 nested ajax calls.  The first ajax call retrieves a list with tasks, on success a loop iterates over the result and makes an ajax call for every result. And on success on these calls data is retrieved to build the chart.

Inside the last success function an `for loop` runs to build an array containing the data for the chart.

These data get pushed into the parameter array for the chart (morris.js).

So 3 nested ajax call, with an `$.each` loop after the first call.

My problem is that the charts gets build for each ajax iteration. I have been trying to move the chart function (`Morris.Donut(params);`) outside of loop without luck.

My code:

```
var arr = [];
var counts = [];
var test = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests?$filter=TaskStatusValue%20eq%20%27Not%20Started%27",
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(a, data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.RequesterId + ")/CreatedBy",
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                },
                success: function(data2) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.AssignedToId + ")/AssignedTo",
                        headers: {
                            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                        },
                        success: function(data3) {
                            var params = {
                                element: 'taskchart',
                                data: [],
                                colors: ['#b85f28', '#d46125', '#CE4E00']
                            };
                            $(".inner").prepend('<p>'+data.Request +' <br>Submitted by: '+data2.d.Name+'<br>Assigned to: '+data3.d.Name+' | Due in: '+data.DueInDays+' day(s)</p>');
                            var indexOfName = arr.indexOf(data3.d.Name);
                            if (indexOfName == -1) {
                                arr.push(data3.d.Name);
                                counts.push(1);
                            } else {
                                counts[indexOfName] ++;
                            }
                            for (var i in arr, counts) {
                                test = {
                                    'label': '' + arr[i] + '',
                                    'value': counts[i]
                                }
                                params.data.push(test);
                            }
                            Morris.Donut(params);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

I know this code can look a bit messy, but I can't seem to build it better. Any suggestions on how I can build the chart after the ajax calls have finished loading the data?

I'm really banging my head against the wall here.

Comment: Your `data2` isn't used anywhere.

Comment: Also, since these are essentially sequential calls, you can try setting the `async` option of all your `$.ajax` calls to `false`. Things probably get out of order in the `$.each` loop.

Comment: My mistake. I did use this before to display some other data, but I didn't include because it wasn't relevant to my question. Will edit right away.

Comment: Async didn't seem to make a difference. How can I properly chain succes call with callbacks? For example`function ajax1(data){
   $.ajax({
         url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests?$filter=TaskStatusValue%20eq%20%27Not%20Started%27",
         headers: {
             'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
             'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    }, ajax2();
   })
  };
 ` Would that be right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Quick Rundown of The Problem***

After looking through your codes more closely, the reason why your chart is re-built for each iteration in your `$.each` function is because your `Morris.Donut(params);` is called within the deepest nested `success` callback in your loop (duh?). And moving `Morris.Donut(params);` outside of your `$.each` function won't work simply because of the asynchronous nature of your nested ajax calls, i.e. the call to `$.each` probably exits and `Morris.Donut(params);` is invoked, before the ajax calls are completed.

***An Easier Alternate (Server-Side) Solution***

Before showing you some javascript codes, I recommend that if you have control over the server-side API codes, you should consider moving all these complexity there; i.e. create a new web service that accepts an `TaskStatusValue` input, and returns IT requests that satisfy this condition along with whatever other information (requester's name, assignee's name etc.) is needed to construct your charts. I think essentially, that's what your JS codes are trying to do.

As I mentioned in my previous comment, your nested AJAX calls rely on results of the parent AJAX call, which essentially, boils down to making synchronous requests, defeating the purpose of asynchronous calls.

***The JQuery Solution (TL;DR)***

With that being said, if you absolutely have to do everything on the client side, we will need to pass an array of [`jQuery.deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects to the [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function such that your chart will be drawn only after all your asynchronous calls are completed.

There can be other easier, better way to do this. But here's my solution....

***Code Refactoring***

Extract your two nested AJAX calls into one separate function like the following. This function will return the `Deferred` object returned by the `$.ajax` function:

```
function retrieveITRequestsFrom(url){
  return $.ajax(url, {
           headers: {
             'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
             'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
           },
           /* etc */
         });
}
```

After getting all the IT requests with `TaskStatusValue=NotStarted` in your first `success` callback, add all the AJAX (Deferred objects) calls you will be making later to an array like this:

```
deferreds = []
$.each(data.results, function(){
    var requesterURL = 'http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(' + this.RequesterId + ')/CreatedBy';
    deferreds.push(retrieveITRequestsFrom(requesterURL));

    var assigneeURL = 'http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(' + this.AssignedToId + ')/AssignedTo';
    deferreds.push(retrieveITRequestsFrom(assigneeURL));        
});
```

Then finally, you can pass this array of `Deferred` objects to the `$.when` function.

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds)
 .then(function(){
     $.each(arguments, function(){
         console.log(this[0]);
     });
})
```

The pseudo-array [`arguments`](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/) within the `$.each` function should contain all the results gathered from all your ajax calls. You can possibly draw your chart within the `then` callback.

I experimented with this using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/kh3tp06e/), using some fake data.

Answer (score -3):

> 1. Change the last two ajax calls as synchronous (by adding option
>      async:false)
> 2. Move the params object to the declaration section
> 3. Move the  morris.donut(params) line to the end of the 1st ajax call success function
>      I have change the whole code block from the above (you question's code) with these changes

```
var arr = [];
    var counts = [];
    var test = [];
    var params = {
        element: 'taskchart',
        data: [],
        colors: ['#b85f28', '#d46125', '#CE4E00']
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests?$filter=TaskStatusValue%20eq%20%27Not%20Started%27",
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(a, data) {
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.RequesterId + ")/CreatedBy",
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                    },
                    success: function(data2) {
                        $.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.AssignedToId + ")/AssignedTo",
                            headers: {
                                'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                                'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                            },
                            success: function(data3) {

                                var indexOfName = arr.indexOf(data3.d.Name);
                                if (indexOfName == -1) {
                                    arr.push(data3.d.Name);
                                    counts.push(1);
                                } else {
                                    counts[indexOfName] ++;
                                }
                                for (var i in arr, counts) {
                                    test = {
                                        'label': '' + arr[i] + '',
                                        'value': counts[i]
                                    }
                                    params.data.push(test);
                                }

                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
             Morris.Donut(params);
        }   
    })
```

Comment: This is a massive wodge of code with no explanation as to what has been changed or why it should make a difference. It is a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.